# XPath - Select element which has an exact number of specific sub-node

Tags: xpath

Let's take this HTML:

```
<html>
    <body>

        <div> <!-- THIS DIV -->
            <div>
                <svg width="100" height="100"><circle cx="6" cy="6" r="5" fill="black"/></svg>
            </div>
            <div>
                <svg width="100" height="100"><circle cx="6" cy="6" r="5" fill="black"/></svg>
            </div>
            <div>
                <svg width="100" height="100"><circle cx="6" cy="6" r="5" fill="black"/></svg>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
        </div>

        <div>
            <div>
                <svg width="100" height="100"><circle cx="6" cy="6" r="5" fill="black"/></svg>
            </div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

I want to select the `div` which has as sub-node exact 3 `svg`.

I was thinking like this: `/div[ count( .//*[local-name() = 'svg'] ) = 3 ]` but not work.

Comment: //div[count(.//svg) = 3]

Comment: @Slkrasnodar I need this XPath in Selenium, and XPath version from Selenium does not detect `svg` elements like how you declared it. Instead work like this `*[local-name() = 'svg']`

Comment: sorry, I don't do selenium but how about  //div[count(.//*[lower-case(local-name()) = 'svg']) = 3]

Answer (score 0):

The suggestion by @Slkrasnodar should work, but I doubt selenium supports XPath 2.0 and `lower-case()` is a 2.0+ function.

Try without it:

```xml
//div[count(.//*[local-name() = 'svg']) = 3]
```

Also, the reason just "svg" doesn't work is because the svg element is in a default namespace. (This is an assumption based on `local-name()` working; the sample in your question does not have a default namespace.)

You should see if selenium has a way to bind the namespace uri to a prefix and use it in your XPath expressions.